# How to interpret System-On-Chip cpu vendor string?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpuid

Intel Manual defines the `cpuid` leaf `0x17` to be responsible for cpu vendor string. The output depends on the value in `ecx`. So according to the note:

> Leaf 17H output depends on the initial value in `ECX`. SOC Vendor
>   Brand String is a UTF-8 encoded string padded with trailing bytes of
>   00H.The complete SOC Vendor Brand String is constructed by
>   concatenating in ascending order of `EAX:EBX:ECX:EDX` and from the
>   sub-leaf 1 fragment towards sub-leaf 3.

I wrote the following assembly and expected to get some sensible string:

```
;Set the System-On-Chip value to eax
mov eax, 0x17

;Set the first subleaf in ecx
mov ecx, 0x01

cpuid
```

The result of the `cpuid` instruction is the following:

```
(gdb) p/x $eax
$8 = 0x7d0
(gdb) p/x $ebx
$9 = 0xfa0
(gdb) p/x $ecx
$10 = 0x64
(gdb) p/x $edx
$11 = 0x0
```

Simply concatenating the register content (throwing away trailing `0x00` bytes) does not result in something readable:

```
$1 = 0x7fffffffdea0 "d\240\017\320\a"
```

***QUESTION:*** How to interpret SOC vendor string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your processor doesn't support cpuid leaf 0x17. Use cpuid leaf 0 to find out the maximum supported cpuid leaf (returned in eax). For example, on my system, the maximum cpuid leaf is 0x0f. When cpuid is used with a leaf value greater than the maximum supported value, the processor returns results from the maximum supported value, which is why you are getting what appear to be garbage values. (If you try cpuid leaf 0x16, you will see that you get the exact same return values as you do with 0x17.)

Comment: Exactly. On my CPU the maximum value turned out to be `0x16`.